# Does the secure browser in "Good for Enterprise" support SQLite?

Tags: ipad, html, browser

The "Good For Enterprise" solution from good.com is a very very difficult thing to google for!

It comes with a secure browser that... well, if you don't know by all means read all about it, but you probably can't answer my question :-)

Which is: does the secure browser (on the iPad specifically) support the SQLite database (or similar), and if so does that data get persisted when the Good "session" ends? From what I can tell, the browser clears its cache when the session is ended - but I'm not sure if that would include stuff like this.

I'm trying to figure out whether I can create an offline-capable web application that will be a front-end to a CRM system. The web app would have to cache CRM data locally, and that would need to persist between sessions. The browser does not currently fully support HTML5 - and so I'm not even sure that SQLite or similar will be available, but it does have some support for HTML5 features. I'm just not sure of the extent of that support...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the document which lists out the secure browser's HTML5 compatibility.

http://media.www1.good.com/documents/SecureBrowser.pdf

As for your question, I don't think you can do this right now because all cached data will be removed once the Good session ends.

Comment: Thanks. I'd found that, but it was too high-level (and ambiguous) so I was hoping for something more specific. But the removal of cached data makes the whole thing a non-starter...

Answer (score 1):

See [**Good Mobile Access (Secure Browser): Support for HTML5 and CSS3**](http://media.www1.good.com/documents/Support+for+HTML5+and+CSS3.pdf) for a much more thorough list of supported features.

Acccording to this document, SQLite databases are not supported by the Secure Browser.